# can't minify images using the grunt plugin grunt-contrib-imagemin

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I just downloaded a fresh copy of yeoman. When I build using grunt, I see that all my images have been converted and their file names have been renamed.

However, the references in the html file do not reference the new names.

Any idea why?

```
imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
      src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img'
    }]
  }
},

usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
  }
},
```

**ngapp/views/main.html**

```
<a href="#red-green" style="background-image: url('img/demo/red-green.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;"></a>
```

Comment: What is it renaming them too?

Comment: 819d856e.red-green.png

Answer (score 2):

Renaming is done by the [`grunt-filerev`](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) task in your Gruntfile. The [`usemin`](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) task takes care of updating the references to those renamed files for scripts, stylesheets and images, but doesn't support inline styles. You should either move the `background-image` reference within a stylesheet or disable the `rev` task.

Comment: adding it on the stylesheet doesn't work either. It remained unminified. eg. body{background-image:url(img/demo/red-green.png)} - that didn't change

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that your url for the image in your HTML file is a relative path and and usemin can't resolve the new path of the image to your url.   See @eddiemonge comment on github for a better explanation: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/108

I had the same problem and fixed it by using a fixed path (/img/demo/red-green.png, in your case) which works fine as long as your distribution directory uses /img and img is also off the root of your app when doing development.

Comment: That wouldn't be the case here, as the original images were renamed. So it's not a path issue, it's a filename reference not being updated (his stylesheet). I'm having the same problem as him.

Comment: Nicholas, in my case the image files were renamed, too, and it was the filename reference as you state.  The article I mentioned above explains this same issue.